# android webview load http content from own device(localhost)

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to write an app that streams the camera on an android tablet via mjpeg.  I have the mjpeg streaming working, and if I connect to my phone from the pc with firefox, I can see the stream from the camera.

However if I try from the same app to use a webview, I can not seem to load the image from either http://localhost:8080/ or http://127.0.0.1:8080/ even though the server is on the device itself, and is listing on port 8080.

On my main activity I have code like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSurfaceHolderHandlerFront=new SurfaceHolderHandler(1,false,8080,PREF_PREVIEW_SIZE_INDEX_DEF,PREF_JPEG_QUALITY_DEF);
    mSurfaceHolderHandlerFront.setPreviewDisplay(((SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mainsurfaceviewfront)).getHolder());

    final PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);

    mSurfaceHolderHandlerFront.tryStartCameraStreamer();

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/camera.html");
}
```

My camera.html file looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>Camera Tools</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top"><img alt="Camera View" border="0" src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/" style="height: 527px" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-top:5px" >
            <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                <tr>
                    <td>Single View</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Multi-View</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>



    </body>
</html>
```

Now I am on a path to madness here, as I have literally tried everything except smashing my device, and it just wont load from the local source.  It did it once, and I have not been able to repeat it.  I dont know if it was code I changed or something else, but I do not know how to debug this.  The internal server mjpeg webserver works correctly if I access it over wifi from my pc, and my page works fine if I access a remote mjpeg cam.  However as soon as I try loading it from the phone itself where the server is running, then nothing.  When debugging, I can not get a breakpoint hit on the socket connection from the local webview, so its almost like its not even trying to load from localhost.  Do I perhaps need to register some permission or something for this to work ?

Note: I am testing this code on an ASUS FE170CG Fonepad tablet. It is running Android Kitkat 4.4.2.

Can anyone suggest anything that might help ?

Thanks,

Steed.

Comment: I'd consider having your server serve up the HTML and CSS (e.g., have the images at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/stream`). Not only would this keep everything on the same host, but it will allow you to test with other on-device browsers, to see if they can successfully access the content. "Do I perhaps need to register some permission or something for this to work ? " -- well, presumably you have `INTERNET` already; you should not need anything else. Also, is your server actually looking for connections from 127.0.0.1, or just from the regular interface?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I do have the 

   <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        android:required="true" />

in my manifest file.

Comment: I am using the peepers mjpeg server from here that I modded into my project.  It is mostly unchanged. link here https://foxdogstudios.com/peepers

it uses the line serverSocket = new ServerSocket(mPort); where mPort would be 8080.  So I would assume that would bind to 0.0.0.0:8080 and so be listening on all interfaces.  When I am on wifi my dhcp server gives the tablet an ip of 192.168.0.66 and if I put http://192.168.0.66:8080/ into firefox on my pc I get the camera stream first time. However even if I try this in my camera.html page, it still wont load on the tablet itself.